# Core plot objective-c, I am using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic, Minor ticks values are not coming?

Tags: core-plot

I am making graph in objective-c by using core-plot library. I am using yAxis.labelPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic but it only showing the y-axis major ticks not showing values on minor ticks! How can I make minor ticks values visible ?

Comment: Can we put labels on minor ticks axis ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `minorTickLabelFormatter` to an [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object. This is identical to the `labelFormatter` property, except that it specifies the format for the labels on the minor tick marks. Use the `minorTickLabelTextStyle` to control the text style of the labels.

Comment: minorTickLabels are over Writting the majorTickLabels, How to solve this problem?